# Error in Python - Unexpected Indent

Tags: python

```
# Use the file name mbox-short.txt as the file name
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
count = 0
avg = 0
fh = open(fname)
for line in fh:
    if not line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:") :    
        continue

    count = count + 1
    pos = line.find(":")
    new = float(line[pos+1:])
    avg = avg + new

print "Done",count,avg
```

I get the following error for this code:

```
line 11
IndentationError : unexpected indent
```

Please help me out. This stuff may seem stupid to some but pardon me, I'm a noob. Thanks in advance

Comment: You are probably mixing tabs and spaces somewhere. Run the script with `python -tt` to detect where this is going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure you are not indenting using `Tab` and `Space` at the same time.

If you mixing `Tab` and `Space` when indenting, python will be confused. I good practice is to set your text editor's auto indentation to the same indentation you preferred. This way, in case you need to manually change indentation, your indentation will be consistent with those created by your text editor.

Comment: whoever downvoted my answer, mind letting me know why? I think mixing tab and space is the reason OP received the error, isn't it?

Comment: `not using Tab and Space at the same time` sounds like `don't press Tab and Space at the same time` - write more accurately.

Comment: Thank you that helped. I was using tab for that line and spaces for others

Comment: @user3600999 glad I helped. I added some to my answer, hope it helps you more.